# pg_restore WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 62

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin-4

I was given a database file , i don't know the userid who dumped it or it's privileges .

I use postgresql 9.6.7-1 with pg_admin4(v3.0) , OS: windows 10

1. First, i created a database in pgadmin with same name as the given file.
2. I used the `restore` option to restore the file but after some seconds

i got type of messages like :

```
pg_restore: executing SEQUENCE SET xxxx
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 4309; 0 0 SEQUENCE SET xxxx postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "public.xxxx" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.xxxx', 1, false);
                             ^
Command was: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.xxxx', 1, false);
```

and below all, the warning :

> "WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 62"

comparing with other's answers i dont even get a single bit of data restored.

I have tried also with

```
pg_restore
```

command but i get the same result .

Comment: What are the 62 errors that were ignored?

Comment: i added the type of errors as an edit to my question

Comment: Maybe 'xxxx' exists, but in a different  schema ? In the script, find out how/if xxxx is created.

Comment: As i see the first half of these warnings have similar output but with the command "COPY" public.xxxx (column1,column2,...) FROM stdin;  instead of "SELECT".                                
Nothing about "create" so far . When u mean in a different schema , u mean different database ? .

Comment: No,when I say `schema`, I mean *schema*. And: the `select setval('xxxx', 1234);` is normally added at the end of the load-script to set the sequence values to the max occurring number in the corresponding table-column.

Comment: In conclusion , the warning issue is due to another file that has already created the corresponding tables ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the dump you were given is not a complete backup.  It only has the data, not the object definitions.  That is, it was created by pg_dump using `-a`, `--data-only`, or `--section=data`.

Unless you already know what the object definitions are from some other source (e.g., an existing database server with the same schema definitions, or a dump file generated with `pg_dump -s`), you will have a hard time loading this data.

Comment: You were actually right , i request about the definitions and i was given the same file with the necessary sql scripts and worked fine after the restore .

Answer (score -2):

{solved}
please check the **version of the Postgresql pgAdmin4** and the ****version of ".Sql"** file** you want to import into your database ,and instead of restoring at public you should directly restore at the database itself.

**2:-** drop the database and again re-create the fresh **database(name='xyz')** & at the same database **(**'xyz'** ->RightClick->Restore->Filename->'select(**formate ".sql")**->Restore**) than->**refresh** the database.
and by doing that it'll create i new Schema just above public Schema..